# Sending data through Com port in windows mobile (compact framework)

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, serial-port

I need to have a virtual com port created so that when the device(windows mobile) usb port is connected to Tracking box serial port has the lead put into it a com port is added to the device. I want to sends the data via the com port using  gprs to a specified address and port number that we set in the tracking box

Answer (score 0):

The [SerialPor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)t class should support that. Have a look at it at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx).

As the version information tells, it is compliant with .NET CF 3.5 & 2.0